# How to loop through the data in database fetched using .list in grails?

Tags: grails

I have a controller with an action that looks like this

```
def createGraph(){
    def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.list()
    //loop through the data and parse
    //render graph
}
```

I need to parse the data fetched and use it in **[google chart plugin](https://grails.org/wiki/Google%20Chart%20Plugin)**.

How will I be able to loop through all the values then pass the data to the view?

Comment: If the `DailyProfit.list()` returned any `Collection` then you're able to iterate through the `dailyProfit.each { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass your data set to the GSP like:

```
def chart(){
def dataset = DailyProfit.list()
[dataset: dataset]
}
```

Then each your list dataset in the GSP:

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
        'modules':[{
          'name':'visualization',
          'version':'1',
          'packages':['corechart']
        }]
      }">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['time', 'sales'],
<g:each in="${dataset}" var="row" status="i">['${row.time}', ${row.sales}],</g:each>

]);         


    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById   ('curve_chart'));

       chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
      </head>
      <body>
   <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that DailyProfit.list() returns a Collection. If so, you can loop over it easily with "each" and a closure: 
In the following example, I'll use the "list" method to obtain a list of datas, then i'll parse them and put it in a new list, which I'll render in a view :

```
def createGraph(){
    def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.list()
    def parsedDatas = []
    //looping and parsing
    dailyProfit.each
    {
      def parsedObject = Toolbox.verifyAndParse(it) //returns a parsedObject
      parsedDatas.add(parsedObject)
    }
    //Rendering
    render(view : "/domain/myView", model:[listProducts: listProducts])
}
```

When using "each" and a closure, "it" designate the particular instance you're looking at in the collection.

Some examples here : [Examples of iteration over collections](http://grails.asia/groovy-each-examples)

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `collect()` instead of `each()`:

```
def createGraph(){
    def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.list().collect{ [ chartA:it.a + it.b, chartB:it.c ] }
    render dailyProfit as JSON
}
```